# How to write task which run multiple tasks with args?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rake, task

I would like to run task for each model like below:

```
task all: :environment do
  resources = [ Question,
                Answer,
                Link,
                Event,
                PastEvent,
                Review ]
  resources.each do |resource|
    #Rake::Task["tire:import CLASS=#{resource} FORCE=true"].execute
    system "rake environment tire:import CLASS='#{resource}' FORCE=true"
  end
end
```

Is better way to use `system` for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  `Rake::Task["<your_task>"].invoke(<params>)`.

Eg: `Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke`.

`invoke` runs the dependencies as well unlike `execute`. If the task has already been invoked, you'll need to do use `reenable` ie `Rake::Task["<your_task>"].reenable`